# Are .NET Compact Framework apps compatible with Windows Phone 7?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, compact-framework

Old .NET Compact Framework apps still run on Windows Phone 7? Will new apps developed with .NET 3.5 run on WP7? I mean, not Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll need to use [CF version 3.7 (or greater)](http://windowsphone.interopbridges.com/articles/chapter-1-windows-phone-7-platform-introduced-to-iphone-application-developers), which only targets Windows Phone devices.

Comment: I don't know any version of .NET between 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: There's no version 3.7 of the standard framework, but there is a version 3.7 of the Compact Framework.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to download or a link where to find more information?

Comment: @Lester: see my update - scroll down to "Comparing the WP7 Programming Stack with the iPhone Stack". Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff380145 for some getting-started guides.

Comment: @Michael: I'm looking for a more simple answer to my question. I would to know if traditional .NET Compact Framework will run on Windows Phone 7. I'm not asking how to start developing apps for Windows Phone 7. Thanks for the info, any way.

Comment: @Lester: I think that article answers your question, but I'm glad you got what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Windows ce/windows mobile/compact framework apps will not run on wp7.

Answer (score 0):

No they do not. You will need to create them using C#. To debug you need the developer tools. These tools will guide you. Here's the link.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49B9D0C5-6597-4313-912A-F0CCA9C7D277&displaylang=en